# tkinter PhotoImage with variable name for each list item

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-canvas, tkinter-button

I am trying to use images in tkinter radiobutton with varying items in my list. For loop is working good. Just getting PhotoImage error while generating variable path for each item.

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

win = Tk()
win.title("Review demo")
win.geometry("900x600")
win.minsize(900, 600)
win.maxsize(900, 600)

choices = ["like", "dislike", "love", "garbage"]
x = IntVar()
img = StringVar() # img declaration doesn't work


for r in range(len(choices)):
    item_name = choices[r]
    path = item_name+".png"
    img = PhotoImage(file = path )
    # img = PhotoImage(file = item_name+'.png')
    radiobtn = Radiobutton(win,
                           text=item_name,
                           variable=x,
                           value=r,
                           padx=20,
                           pady=20,
                           image= img
                           )
    radiobtn.pack(anchor=E)

win.mainloop()
```

errors i am getting is

```
    img = PhotoImage(file = item_name+'.png')
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Rohit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 4130, in __init__
    Image.__init__(self, 'photo', name, cnf, master, **kw)
  File "C:\Users\Rohit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 4075, in __init__
    self.tk.call(('image', 'create', imgtype, name,) + options)
_tkinter.TclError: couldn't recognize data in image file "like.png"
```

Comment: Are you certain that "like.png" is actually a png file? Could it be some other format (eg: like.jpg) that you just renamed to have a .png suffix?

Comment: @BryanOakley yes, 100% sure. I still couldn't find a way to use PhotoImage with for loop. a workaround worked me though. I created a separate list with ImageTk.PhotoImage paths with needed dimensions and then inside the loop just used index number to call that path in image list.

If you still find a way to use photoimage in loop than please let me know. It will save a lot of time. and lesser code is always good ;)

Comment: `tkinter.PhotoImage()` may not support latest PNG format. Use `ImageTk.PhotoImage()` instead.

Comment: @acw1668 tried that. doesn't work inside loop

Comment: It is because you use same variable for all the images so only the last one will be shown.

Comment: @acw1668 i think i am missing something of what you are trying to say. I couldn't find a way to use PhotoImage with for loop, even with ImageTk. To solve the issue I created a separate list with ImageTk.PhotoImage paths with needed dimensions and then inside the loop just used index number on that image list to get that image path. If you find a way to use photoimage in loop than please let me know. It will help a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I think we cannot use PhotoImage inside loop even with the help of ImageTk. So created a way around by creating a separate list of images path

```
choice_images = []
for choice in choices:      
   image = Image.open(choice+'.png')
   resized_image = image.resize((100, 100))
   final_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(resized_image)
   choice_images.append(final_image)

# generating radio buttons with respective images
x = IntVar()
for r in range(len(choices)):
   radiobtn = Radiobutton(win,
                        text=choices[r],
                        variable=x,
                        value=r,
                        font=("Noto Sans", 20),
                        image= choice_images[r],
                        compound= 'right',
                        command=rate_item
                        )
   radiobtn.pack(anchor=E)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you use same variable `img` to save the references of the images, so only the last image has variable referencing it after the for loop and the previous images are garbage collected.

You can use an attribute of the radiobutton to store the reference of the image as below:

```py
for r in range(len(choices)):
    item_name = choices[r]
    path = item_name+".png"
    # use ImageTk.PhotoImage instead of PhotoImage
    # to support latest PNG format
    img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file=path)
    radiobtn = Radiobutton(win,
                           text=item_name,
                           variable=x,
                           value=r,
                           padx=20,
                           pady=20,
                           image=img
                           )
    radiobtn.pack(anchor=E)
    radiobtn.image = img # save the reference of the image
```

Comment: that is quite helpful. i used this image resize. one thing i would like to ask is why we need to pass img in 2 different place?  couldn't understand why this reference is even needed. can you please explain a little?

Comment: As said, if the references of those images are not saved, they will be garbage collected.